# My java web start application only starts when verbose is set

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a java web start application, that I try to start via

```
javaws.exe https://localhost:8888/myApplication/myApplication.jnlp
```

nothing happens (no error message; I see no process starting in the task list).

If I start it via

```
javaws.exe -verbose https://localhost:8888/myApplication/myApplication.jnlp
```

the application starts.

I can also start the application when using

```
javaws.exe -viewer https://localhost:8888/myApplication/myApplication.jnlp
```

and then starting the application from the *java cache viewer*.

What is the difference, that might trigger the application to run, when in verbose mode or via the viewer? Here is my jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://localhost:8888/myApplication" href="myApplication.jnlp">
    <information>
        ....
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8.0_60+"         href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"          max-heap-size="500m" initial-heap-size="250m"/>
        <!-- some jars are referenced -->
        <property name="sun.java2d.d3d" value="false" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows">
        <nativelib href="mylib.jar" download="eager" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="myClass">
        <argument>-initLogging</argument>
        <argument>SETPROPERTYjavax.net.ssl.trustStore</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>SETPROPERTYjavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>SETPROPERTYjavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>-locale</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>-serviceHost</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>-serviceProtocol</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>-servicePort</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
        <argument>-trustStrategy</argument>
        <argument>_UNDEFINED_</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem, too (see my comment [My java web start application only starts when verbose is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570931/my-java-web-start-application-only-starts-when-verbose-is-set#comment70676448_37572139))

I solved this problem by updating Java, i.e. reinstalling Java. The file `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg` was created again and this new java installation could open web start applications again correctly. Although older versions still had the same bug.

Answer (score 2):

I activated the trace and log output and found an Exception occured:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.readSystemConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getSponsorOffersDisabledSettings(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.config.ClientConfig.getSponsorOffersDisabledSettings(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.AdvancedProperties.saveSponsorOfferingSettings(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchJavaControlPanel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then I found this page:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134475

When I activate the java browser content (Java Control Panel > Security Tab > select checkbox "Enable content for browser and Web Start application").
Then the application started...

But the problem is: I do not know why!

Comment: I did only one change and that must be the reason. I opened the Java Control Panel from Windows System Settings and changed the Security configurations from High to Very High. After some tests I switched back to High. Since this actions I have the same problem. I didn't change the Java in Browser Checkbox at all.

Answer (score 0):

After an update of Java with Java 9 I need to "Enable Applets and Web Start in the browser" in the security tab of the Java control panel.